# precision, recall, F1 metrics exclude a label sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, metrics, multiclass-classification

I have a classifier for a NER task, and since `'O'` labels are by far more than all others, I want to exclude it in metrics calculation.

I want to compute `macro` and `micro` scores with `sklearn` package. Macro scores can be calculated with `precision_recall_fscore_support`, because it returns the `precision`, `recall`, `F1` and `support` for each label separetly.

Can I use `sklearn` package to compute and `micro` scores as well?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be very simple. The `label` parameter of the function determines which labels to include in scores calculation. It is also combined with the `macro`, `micro` averages.